# Setting a textbox property value within a catch block

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, try-catch

Using VS 2013 VB.net for my ClickOnce application. I've got a function which verifies database functionality and the guts are wrapped in a `Try Catch`. A portion of my Catch block looks like this:

```
Catch ex As Exception When Err.Number = "5"

        My.Application.Log.WriteException(ex)

        If My.Settings.g_blnDebugMode Then
            MessageBox.Show(Err.Number & " " & ex.ToString, "Exception Error")
        End If

        If Err.Description.Contains("The specified table does not exist") Then
            MessageBox.Show("Selected file is not a valid database.", "Exception Error")
        ElseIf Err.Description.Contains("The specified password does not match the database password.") Then
            MessageBox.Show("The specified password does not match the current database password.", "Exception Error")
        End If

        Return False
```

[image: Intellisense Error]

What I want to do is, clear two different fields based on the two custom error messages at the bottom. Something like `TextBox1.Text = ""` or `TextBox2.Text = ""` depending on which error is thrown (invalid password or invalid database). My problem is that I don't seem to be able to set them directly or set the value of a module or global variable from within the catch block.

Error is:

> *Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class.*

If it's possible how can I work around this and set my TextBoxes based on the results in the Catch block?

Comment: Did you used `Breakpoint` to trace ? At which point this error occurring ?

Comment: @Mahadev it's an intellisense error on the code page

Comment: OK. but exactly where ?

Comment: If I add txtFile.text = "" directly under the MessageBox.Show line it's underlined in blue. Float your mouse over it and you get the error above. I added a picture to the bottom of my original post for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the method to achieve what you are trying is to use a second a catch block

```
Catch ex As Exception When Err.Number = ""
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    FlushTextBox1();
Catch ex As Exception When Err.Number = ""
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    FlushTextBox2();
```

The error is likely appearing because the try-catch block is inside a `Shared` method. What that means is, the change in the value of `TextBox` will be repeated for all instances of the class. If you want the `TextBox` to behave like this, add the `Shared` keyword to its own declaration and remove it from the Sub's declaration. If you don't want this behaviour at all, just remove the `Shared` keyword. For more information on the error check the MSDN [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfsswe45.aspx)

Alternatively you can call a local function (as shown in code) `FlushTextBox1()` to change the value of the `TextBox` outside the Sub.

Comment: Trying to call another method doesn't work for me with the same error in my original post. Taking the SHARED off worked and that's great. I'll work on my understanding and see if I can handle this situation better if I do want it SHARED. Thank you.

Comment: Oh so calling the method didn't work? I learned something to haha Glad to be a help

Comment: Just to be clear it works just fine (calling another method) once you take the SHARED off just doesn't work with it on. Which may be what you were telling me to do. If so then my bad man.